# Why this error happened? "ImportError: cannot import name 'multi_worker_mirrored_2x1_cpu' from 'tensorflow.python.distribute.strategy_combinations'"

Tags: python

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-90ed6c760dd4> in <module>
----> 1 from tensorflow.keras import layers, models, optimizers
      2 import tensorflow as tf
      3 import cv2
      4 import numpy as np
      5 import glob

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     47 _tf2.enable()
     48 
---> 49 from ._api.v2 import __internal__
     50 from ._api.v2 import __operators__
     51 from ._api.v2 import audio

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\__internal__\__init__.py in <module>
      9 
     10 from . import decorator
---> 11 from . import distribute
     12 from . import test
     13 from . import tracking

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\__internal__\distribute\__init__.py in <module>
      8 import sys as _sys
      9 
---> 10 from . import combinations
     11 from . import multi_process_runner
     12 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\__internal__\distribute\combinations\__init__.py in <module>
     18 from tensorflow.python.distribute.strategy_combinations import mirrored_strategy_with_one_gpu
     19 from tensorflow.python.distribute.strategy_combinations import mirrored_strategy_with_two_gpus
---> 20 from tensorflow.python.distribute.strategy_combinations import multi_worker_mirrored_2x1_cpu
     21 from tensorflow.python.distribute.strategy_combinations import multi_worker_mirrored_2x1_gpu
     22 from tensorflow.python.distribute.strategy_combinations import multi_worker_mirrored_2x2_gpu

ImportError: cannot import name 'multi_worker_mirrored_2x1_cpu' from 'tensorflow.python.distribute.strategy_combinations' (C:\Users\Noosi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\strategy_combinations.py)
1
# np.expand_dims(np.full((416, 416, 3), 1, dtype='float32'), 0)
```